# parseFloat method not giving proper output

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

Here is a sample program:

```js
var a = parseFloat("86.69043189999999") + "<br>";
var b = parseFloat("86.79718199999999") + "<br>";
var n = a + b;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

```html
<p id=demo></p>
```

Both the two variables have exact same decimal point still it's giving two different kind of output:

```
86.6904319
86.79718199999999
```

Why such an weird behaviour?

Comment: I can't give a complete answer, but I have a feeling the root of the problem may stem from the fact that floats are inherently weird: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript